# How delete paperclip item with checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, paperclip

I have the next code in a partial _form of my view:

```
<%= f.label :logo %><br />
<% if f.object.new_record? %>
  <%= f.file_field :logo %>
<% elsif %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(f.object.logo.url(:thumb)), f.object.logo.url(:original) %>
  <%= f.check_box %>
<% end %>
```

Im try to delete the object.logo if i select the checkbox and press the edit button. Im do it with Nested items, but this is a simple paperclip implementations.

any help is welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today i get the solution to this issue:

In the brand model:

```
attr_accessible :description, :title, :logo, :delete_logo

#delete existing logo from edit view with checkbox.
attr_accessor :delete_logo
before_validation { logo.clear if delete_logo == '1' }
```

In the brand view _form:

```
<% if @brand.logo? %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(f.object.logo.url(:thumb)), f.object.logo.url(:original) %>
  <%= f.check_box(:delete_logo) %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.file_field :logo %>
<% end %>
```

Works for me.

Comment: Does not work with rails 5. Any update would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can do domething like this:

In the model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :logos, :allow_destroy => true
```

In the form

```
if !f.object.logo_file_name.blank?
  f.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Delete?"
end
```

Hope this help